# Convert basic PHP/MySql to ASP to query MS Sql database

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql-server

I have, what I would think, would be a very easy conversion....I have a database that has 1 table with 4 fields....I query the table to fill the webpage....I need to convert this PHP to .aspx  I've looked and it seems that most of what I find is much more advanced than i need.  I know NOTHING about asp.  Thank you very much.  Here is what I have:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TestMeas ORDER BY name ASC",$connect);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
?>                          

<?php 

echo "<a href=\"".$myrow['url']."\" target=\"_new\">".$myrow['name']. "</a>";  ?>

<?php echo $myrow['desc'];
        }
?>
```

Comment: `I know NOTHING about asp.` -- In the scientific tradition of breaking a problem down, you should maybe start solving this one first... :o)

Comment: @deceze +1 - PHP and ASP are dauntingly different, there's just such a huge gulf in terms of concepts. The only solution is to just learn it, because you can't rely on asking other people for full solutions all the time.

Comment: @Farray, thank you....and the asp-classic just slipped in there.

Comment: @deceze -- I'm sorry..I thought it would be an easy task...I'm just doing this for a favor to a friend and quite honestly think this is it for me and asp =)

Comment: @Joe -- I'm sorry..I thought it would be an easy task...I'm just doing this for a favor to a friend and quite honestly think this is it for me and asp =)

Comment: @KimHathy-Schwartz In that case, your question is missing some needed details.  What version of .Net, what language are you using, etc.

Comment: @Farray.  please forgive my ignorance.  I have recoded a friends website.  It's 99% HTML with a little PHP - only what I've shown you.  He needs to keep his site hosted where it's been forever...I told his hosting company what I have and was told, "just recode that php to asp"...they have a MS Sql database.  The technology they advertise on their website is ASPX, ASP, Classic ASP, ADO, C#, VB...I assumed the code would be minimal and I could figure it out fairly easily...The current site has .aspx files with #C....I have Dreamweaver & MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express...

Comment: @Farray  I assume, once again, I can use what ever I want as long as their Windows Servers will have it...based on their advertised technology?  Thanks for listening....I'd appreciate any help/advise you can give.

Comment: Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C  It's not written with a website in mind, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Farray  Thank you.  That link is broken..but I can probably google it or at least now I have somewhere to start =)  Thanks a lot.  Have a great weekend.

Comment: Click the link, don't copy/paste.  It's not broken...

Comment: @Farray  I click it and I get a screen with little brown guys eating computer equipment... and it says:  Something bad happened

We're not sure what, but we have a few guesses.
Problem: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Ticket: 5159102
Server: Web02

Comment: @Farray - this is in the address bar:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Comment: Weird, maybe CP is blocking SO referred links?  Oh well, open a new browser session and copy/paste the link.  It's the correct address, it just won't work as a direct link.

Comment: I just clicked it again and it worked =)  Looks like this should help me immensely =)  Thank you very much =)

Comment: @Farray -- oops...forgot that =) I just clicked it again and it worked =) Looks like this should help me immensely =) Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there is a big difference between [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) and [ASP.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET).  In very simple terms, ASP is a scripting language whereas ASP.net is an application framework.  Since ASP and PHP are both scripting languages, the usage is fairly similar.  ASP.net is a whole different beast with almost no similarity.

Given the differences between working in a scripting language and working within the structure of the .Net framework, it's difficult to say "just do XYZ to convert your PHP to .Net".  The .Net framework is largely built around separating presentation from content, which is not a focus in PHP unless you use a framework like CakePHP or CodeIgniter (or others).

Hopefully the [linked tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) in the comments got you on your way.  There is also an [MSDN article with a simple example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx) of connecting to SQL Server.

Since this appears to be a "one-off" favor for a friend, your simplest option is probably to build a string in the code and pass it to your view.

```
string output = "";
using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
{
    conn.Open();
    using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "SELECT url, name FROM TestMeas ORDER BY name ASC", 
                                                conn ) )
    {
        using( SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if( reader.HasRows )
            {
                while ( reader.Read() )
                {
                    output += String.Format( "<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_new\">{1}</a>",
                                             reader[ 0 ],
                                             reader[ 1 ] );
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}

// Do something with output
```

You could do this in a code-behind, you could do it in a Controller if you're using MVC, you could do it right in the form/view/page if you want.